# How to get the status for each test steps using Java Selenium ? I would like to know whether the test step is pass, fail or skipped

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, listener

I need to fetch the test status for each steps. I used TestListenerAdapter to get the status of Test Suite & Test cases status. Now I need to know using listeners whether it is possible to fetch the test step status.

Comment: TestListenerAdapter only provides the capability to track down test case level. If you need to know the status of each step in a test case you need to log down each step to a log file. Then, you can track the failure step once a test case getting failed.
 
Another method is to use assertions to make tests fail with meaningful reasons.

Comment: The solution is adding log file for each execution am I right ? @SenalWeerasinghe

Comment: Just check for log4j logging module. 
It has different kinds of rolling policies. You can make a logfile for an entire test suite and log all the steps into it. Log down TestListnerAdapter's logs too.

Comment: Another question, How to return the value from the listener method
`List<Date> date = new ArrayList<Date>();
public void onStart(ITestContext   context) { 
  Date SuiteStartTime= context.getStartDate();
  System.out.println("Starting Time of the TestSuite"+SuiteStartTime);
  
   date.add(SuiteStartTime); 
 }`

Comment: @KogulSelvanathan Don't post code in comments. Instead, update your question, or create a new question. And unless two issues are intimately related they should be in separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

- TestListenerAdapter only provides the capability to track down test case level. If you need to know the status of each step in a test case you need to log down each step to a log file. Then, you can track the failure step once a test case getting failed. Another method is to use assertions to make tests fail with meaningful reasons.
- Example of TestListner

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.testng.*;


public class TestStatusListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestStatusListener.class);
    private static final TestStatusListener testStatusListener;
    private ITestNGMethod iInvokedMethod;

    public ITestNGMethod getInvokedMethod() {
        return iInvokedMethod;
    }

    public void setInvokedMethod(ITestNGMethod iInvokedMethod) {
        this.iInvokedMethod = iInvokedMethod;
    }

    static {
        testStatusListener = new TestStatusListener();
    }

    public static TestStatusListener getTestStatusListener(){
        return testStatusListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(ITestContext testContext) {
        super.onStart(testContext);
        logger.info(String.format("TEST SUITE STARTED |{%s}|",testContext.getSuite().getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ITestContext testContext) {
        super.onFinish(testContext);
        logger.info(String.format("TEST SUITE FINISHED |{%s}|",testContext.getSuite().getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {
        super.onTestSuccess(tr);
        setInvokedMethod(tr.getMethod());
        if (tr.getName() != null) {
            logger.info(String.format("TEST_END_SUCCESSFULLY |{%s},{%s}|",returnMethodName(),
                    tr.getEndMillis() - tr.getStartMillis()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("ThrowableResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
        super.onTestFailure(tr);
        setInvokedMethod(tr.getMethod());
        if (tr.getThrowable() != null)
            logger.error(String.format("Test completed with exception |{%s}|",returnMethodName(),
                    tr.getEndMillis() - tr.getStartMillis()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult tr) {
        super.onTestSkipped(tr);
        setInvokedMethod(tr.getMethod());
        logger.debug(String.format("Test skipped |{%s}|",returnMethodName()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult tr) {
        super.onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(tr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationFailure(ITestResult itr) {
        super.onConfigurationFailure(itr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationSkip(ITestResult itr) {
        super.onConfigurationSkip(itr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationSuccess(ITestResult itr) {
        super.onConfigurationSuccess(itr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
        super.onTestStart(result);
        setInvokedMethod(result.getMethod());
        logger.info(String.format("Test started |{%s}|",returnMethodName()));
    }

    public String returnMethodName() {
        ITestNGMethod method = getInvokedMethod();
        return method.getRealClass().getSimpleName() + "." + method.getMethodName();
    }
}
```

- Sample of Log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
                     xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>


    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="file" value="./log/SurvTest.log" />

        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="./log/SurvTest.%d.log"></param>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                   value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks I will follow the same